# How to deal with referential integrity in optional one-to-one relation?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, database-design, database-schema, prisma

I'm working on a Twitch chat bot where users can create multiple `Pokemon`. When a user sends a message in chat, I am able to see their `oauthId`.  I wanted to store this id in my `Pokemon` model, so that if a user every registers on my site, it can tie their `TwitchUser` account info to the `Pokemon` they already created.

Prisma schema models:

```
// This gets created when a User creates an account
model TwitchUser {
  id                   String    @id @default(uuid())
  oauthId              String    @unique
  displayName          String
  accountCreated       DateTime
  pokemon              Pokemon[]
}

// This can get created _before_ a User account is created
model Pokemon {
  id            String     @id @default(uuid())
  name          String
  twitchOauthId String?
  twitchUser    TwitchUser? @relation(fields: [twitchOauthId], references: [oauthId])
}
```

My query:

```
await this.prisma.pokemon.create({twitchOauthId: 'id_from_user_that_is_not_created', name: 'Pikachu'})
```

The problem is that if I supply a `twitchOauthId` for a `Pokemon`, when a `TwitchUser` is not yet created, I get this error:

```
await this.prisma.post.create(
Foreign key constraint failed on the field: `Pokemon_twitchOAuthId_fkey (index)`
```

I looked into it, and found this in the [Prisma docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/referential-integrity)

`Referential integrity requires that if one record references another, then the referenced record must exist`

I'm not sure if it's possible to accomplish what I want. It seems my only option is to remove the `TwitchUser` and `Pokemon[]` relation from my models, but that defeats the purpose of using a relational db.

I just want to be able to create a `Pokemon` with a `twitchOauthId`, that can later be used to reference a `TwitchUser` when their account is later created with the same `oauthId`.

Comment: You can't have a part time FK. Either: 1) Don't have the relationship. 2) Or add an entry to TwitchUser(before the Pokemon entry) even if they don't register for your site  and add a `registered` boolean field when they do. 3)  Do 1) and have a trigger that fills in the oauthId.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thank you for the suggestions. Is it bad practice to remove the relationship between them? If I were to delete a User, I'd like their Pokemon to be deleted, so I guess I would then have to do that operation manually. I'm leaning towards option 2, but want to know how often to make a decision like that.

Comment: Then add `ON DELETE CASCADE` to the FK reference, that will automatically delete the Pokemon entries related to the deleted User. It all explained in the docs here [Create Table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html). Search for `REFERENCES reftable [ ( refcolumn ) ]` in the page.